# Use 'apply' instead of a nested loop on two matrices

Tags: r, matrix, vectorization, apply, correlation

I have two matrices:

```
first.matrix  = matrix(c(1,1,2,3,3,2,4,1), nrow=2)
second.matrix = matrix(c(2,2,3,3,1,1,4,1), nrow=2)
```

and I want to find the correlation between the rows in 'first.matrix' and the rows in second.matrix. In Java, I would write something like this:

```
results <- data.frame("first"=c(1:4),"second"=c(1:4), "cor"=c(1:4))
counter <- 1
for(i in 1:2) {
  a <- c(t(first.matrix[i,]))
  for(j in 1:2) {
    b <- c(t(second.matrix[j,]))    
    results$cor[counter] <- cor(a,b)
    results$first[counter]  <- i
    results$second[counter] <- j
    counter=counter+1
  }  
}
```

I'm trying to teach myself to code in R in the "right" way, and have spent time reading R-tutorials and questions here on Stack Overflow. So I know my solution requires the use of apply, but try as I can, I don't understand how to actually write it. All the examples I see are pretty simple and involve finding the sum or the mean of a column or row. 
The trouble is:

a. I need an 'apply' that can accommodate a function that receives two variables, a row from each matrix. This requires a little manipulation to retrieve the rows. I can solve this with:

```
c(t(first.matrix[i,]))
```

but I don't know how to insert that to the 'apply'

b. I need results the tell me what row from the first matrix was compared with what row in the second matrix, and what the result is. In my example, running the code I wrote will result in:

```
 first second        cor
1     1      1  0.4000000
2     1      2 -0.6741999
3     2      1 -0.1348400
4     2      2  0.6363636
```

I don't care if the columns have names or not.

Any solution, hint, or reference will be really appreciated :-)

Comment: `cor(t(first.matrix), t(second.matrix))`, and then `reshape2::melt(cor(t(first.matrix), t(second.matrix)))`

Comment: wow!! that's so elegant! If you write it as a solution I'll accept it. I had not idea that 'cor' would perform on a transposed matrix. Now I'm curious: what is the intuition behind that? How was I supposed to know that? I tried 'cor' straight on the matrix and that didn't work of course. Thanks a lot!

Comment: The general term for "use '*apply' family instead of loop/nested loops" is [tag:vectorization]. Please use that tag on this sort of question. And skim the existing questions. The general philosophy in R is that most functions should allow a vector/matrix argument instead of a single number, where it makes sense.

Comment: @smci - I read (not skimmed, took the time to read) all questions I found on `apply`, and I read some tutorials as well. I also read the answers, the comments and the comments on the comments, and there almost always appears a comment such as yours. I did my best to ask the question in the "right way".  Note that my "java-like" R code in the original question does use `cor` on a vector (I know that a function allows more than a number), but it didn't occur to me that I could transpose the matrix and then call the columns as vectors. Pretty obvious, when I rethink about it now.

Comment: @nafrtiti : Sure, you didn't do anything wrong, I wasn't saying you had! Just trying to make sure you know 'vectorize' is the right keyword for next time, and the R philosophy that loops are generally to be avoided, and should be replaceable with vectors/matrices, and wrapped with whatever other functional machinery you need. It took me a lot of getting used to when I originally migrated from Python. Coming from Java is an even harder paradigm shift.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution would be to first merge the # of rows of `first.matrix` to the # of rows of `second.matrix` together to get all the combinations you want. Basically this just gets you the indexes of the matrices you want. Then you could do an `sapply` to get the correlation.

Something like:

```
    res<-merge(data.frame(first=1:nrow(first.matrix)),
               data.frame(second=1:nrow(second.matrix)))
    res$corr<-sapply(1:nrow(res),function(i) {
                        cor(first.matrix[res[i,1],],second.matrix[res[i,2],])
                        })
    res

#   first second       corr
#1     1      1  0.4000000
#2     2      1 -0.1348400
#3     1      2 -0.6741999
#4     2      2  0.6363636
```

Comment: I'm embarrassed to say I don't quite understand this solution, since I don't see a definition of `rows`, so don't understand how this works.

Comment: @nafrtiti that is my fault I'm sorry - I didn't update the names in the code. `rows` should have been `res`. Should work now.

Comment: thanks for the clarification!

Answer (score 2):

You could do this by combining `expand.grid` with `apply`. Use `expand.grid` to get a table with all the possible combinations of rows from the two matrices, then use `apply` to iterate your function over those combinations. Like:

```
apply(# get a table with all possible combinations of rows
      expand.grid(seq(nrow(first.matrix)), seq(nrow(second.matrix))),
      # apply the upcoming function row-wise
      1,
      # now run cor over those combos of row
      function(x) cor(x = first.matrix[x[1],], y = second.matrix[x[2],]))
```

Result:

```
[1]  0.4000000 -0.1348400 -0.6741999  0.6363636
```